# Apache shows wrong version for php

Tags: php, apache

I've installed php 5.4.6 manually on mac snow leopard. But when I config & restart apache and call phpinfo() method it shows php version as 5.3.8 which probabely is the pre-installed system php that comes with Mac OS X.

How should I fix this and tell apache to use php 5.4.6 instead of system php?

Best regards,

Comment: See [OSX Apache using wrong version of PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613313/osx-apache-using-wrong-version-of-php)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to specify which PHP version to use in */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*, look for a line that says:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Uncomment this line and point it to the newest version of PHP you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you updated the Apache php module as well?
Try updating the module `php` simple.
It is the one that ties into Apache and in recent versions is not installed along with the general php installation.

Comment: The only change in apache I made was uncommenting follwing line: LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: That should disable PHP completly.

Comment: Check conf.d folder for a php.conf file.