# OSX Apache using wrong version of PHP

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, php

I followed a guide which used home-brew to install the lastest version of php (5.4.8) on OSX Mountain Lion.

I then followed a guide which showed me how to setup and use the pre-installed apache on OSX.

However when I try running up a base Symfony 2 project I get a bunch of errors relating to missing date.timezone in the php.ini.

However I have this correctly setup the php.ini but doing a quick phpinfo() in the Symfony project shows that its using the old preinstalled version of php (5.3) rather than the new one.

In terminal if I type `which php` & `php -v`, It shows the correct new version is being used.

[image]

But the `phpinfo()` shows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Did you follow all the instructions provided in the Caveats?

Run `brew info php54` to see them again.

Especially the line:

> To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and **restart Apache**:
>   LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: + for answering the specific *HomeBrew* question.

Comment: ahh, I uncommented the default line rather than sticking in the one given to you by homebrew when installing, thanks :D

Comment: If you use "Server.app" and "Websites" consider editing the following /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf in order to use your brewed php when needed … You can then easely rollback to normal use by disabling "Websites" have also a look at /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist if you want to play around with "defaults read/write an array of strings"

Answer (score 3):

Apache is not aware of the *homebrew* version of PHP (i.e. `/usr/bin/php`). You see it on the command line because you've likely modified your `PATH` (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/php`).

You can modify this in your httpd.conf file.

I am not a fan of *homebrew* or other package libraries. Primarily because Mac OS X is built atop Unix. Furthermore, all but MySQL are installed natively. Here's an article on [installing Apache, MySQL, and PHP on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/).

**Disclaimer:** I wrote that article.

Comment: I dont have much in depth computing knowledge, whats wrong with package libraries within a Unix based system :S? The only issue with your guide is that it doest show you how to upgrade to the lastest php :(

Comment: Me neither, but I like learning. Which is probably why I install it myself. Plus, from my experience, package managers fail sooner or later. Similar to any other package, you could always download and compile the latest version of PHP yourself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I have same issue for updating php 7.2 to 7.3 as requirement of Laravel 6. Here is my solution.

1. Open your httpd.conf file in "/etc/apache2/http.conf"
2. Search (Ctrl + w) for "LoadModule php"
3. Uncomment that row
4. Restart your apache with "sudo apachectl restart"

Then, your php version in local web server (apache2) will be updated