# Cannot run artisan for laravel and issue with php version for composer

Tags: php, macos, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I cannot run artisan because of some weird parse error.

```
$ php artisan serve
Parse error: parse error, expecting "identifier (T_STRING)"' or
"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or '{'' or '$'' in
/Library/WebServer/Documents/artisan on line 31
```

So I figure I need to run `composer install`, but then I get this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
packages.

Problem 1
 - This package requires php >=5.5.9 but your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.   Problem 2
 - classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
 - classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version does not satisfy that requirement.
 - Installation request for classpreloader/classpreloader 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by classpreloader/classpreloader[2.0.0].
```

So I try to install php5.5 or whatever it needs which supposedly works.

```
$ curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5 installing...
Installing package 5.5-10.8-frontenddev into root / Package
5.5-10.8-frontenddev is already installed at version
5.5.27-20150710-221744. You wanted to install version
5.5.27-20150710-221744.
```

So at this point, I figure I have met the requirements, but low and behold, same issue with `composer install`.

No idea what's going on here because it seems like this issue has been around for [some time now](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-artisan-parse-error-expecting-identifier-t-string?page=1).

Comment: You are probably using old php in cli. Check with command `php -v`

Comment: PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29) . Should I do something different here?

Comment: So I was right. Try to add new php to your $PATH and remove old one. And ensure your server is also running with new PHP.

Comment: Thank you. If you could be a little more specific, it would help out.

Comment: Take a look here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107230/why-does-my-os-x-still-run-older-php-even-though-i-updated-it or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613313/osx-apache-using-wrong-version-of-php

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to pass [`--ignore-platform-reqs`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) to your `composer` command.

This should work when you can run your composer using the right version of PHP, e.g.

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

---

Another way is to install on macOS different PHP version by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), e.g.

```
brew install php56
brew install php72
```

Then you can link it like:

```
ln -vs /usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php56
ln -vs /usr/local/opt/php72/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php72
```

then you can run composer using PHP version of your choice, e.g.

```
php71 composer install
```