# parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"\\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)"' in EG_14/Starter/cart_additem.php on line 4

Tags: php, identifier

What parsing error is there on line 4?

> parse error, expecting "identifier (T_STRING)"' or "\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)"' in  EG_14/Starter/cart_additem.php on line 4.

```
<?php

//Cart/Db file has create_item function defined.

namespace Cart\App{

    use function Cart\Db\create_item;  //line 4

    $new_id = create_item($cart, [
        'name' => 'HTC m8',
        'price' => 500
    ]);

    $new_item = \Cart\Db\read_item_name($cart, 'HTC m8');
}
```

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: Actually, I use 5.6. but terminal shows 5.5.31 anyway.

Comment: Or not. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300380/apache-shows-wrong-version-for-php) and [this other question](http://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php)

Answer (score 5):

You need to upgrade to PHP 5.6 (or higher) to import functions. The `use function` syntax is not available in Version `5.5.31`.

[Official Documentation on Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)